# Does the "get_payments" JSON RPC call respond with the "locked" value as true *only* if the confimations are below 10?

Tags: monerod, daemon, rpc, api, php

I am creating an e-commerce website that accepts monero using the monero JSON RPC API. I need to make sure the confirmations of a payment for any single order are equal to or above 10, I would like to know if the "locked" boolean value tells me this or if it refers to something else. And if so --- what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the "get_payments" JSON RPC call respond with the "locked" value as true *only* if the confimations are below 10?

No. An output will be locked if 1) the tx is locked till some future time / block, or there are not 10 confirmations.

Source: [1](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/ac02af92867590ca80b2779a7bbeafa99ff94dcb/src/wallet/wallet_rpc_server.cpp#L1907), [2](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/ac02af92867590ca80b2779a7bbeafa99ff94dcb/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp#L6731-L6740).

Comment: Dont know what happened to my orginal comment;

So an unlocked payment output is safe to be recognised as a payment for which I can fulfil an order for? I assume so... But wondering if there are other checks and balances that need to be put in place before sending items.

Comment: If `"locked": false`, then you've received payment, the funds are spendable and you can fulfill the order.